# DB access during "bin/magento setup:di:compile"

Tags: setup-di-compile

I have a project in which DB access is happening during the DI compilation process. My understanding is that there should be no DB access while running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. When I test this theory on a default installation of Magento it holds up. No database access during DI compile. (My testing process is to shut down the DB and then run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`)

I tried removing every custom module from my project, but DB access still happens.

[image: error during DI compile]

The progress bar says 100%, but then something at the very end attempts DB access. What could this be?

For reference `composer.json`. And `app/code/` directory is empty.

```
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
```

Comment: The database access credentials are environmental variables and are configured in `env.php` which can be found under `app/etc` directory. You can change / remove the access from this file to test.

Comment: Add -vvv to command to get a trace

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? if yes then use super user with sudo. 
Ex sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your lampp server

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```